# RTOS can you vTaskSuspend vTaskResume a thread?

Tags: multithreading, stm32, extern, rtos

the tittle is self explanatory.
I have threads declared as such:
in main.c

```
/* Definitions for MainThread */
osThreadId_t MainThreadHandle;
const osThreadAttr_t MainThread_attributes = {
  .name = "MainThread",
  .priority = (osPriority_t) osPriorityNormal,
  .stack_size = 128 * 4
};
```

others declared in the same manner. This is main.c

this particular thread will need to suspend itself, and be resumed of course by another thread.
The issue is that the codes that calls both the suspend and resume functions are in other files.

I have tried doing like I do for other declarations but it's not compiling. here's what I tried:
in main.h

```
/* Exported types ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN ET */
extern osThreadId_t MainThreadHandle;
```

the error I am getting is:

```
../Core/Inc/main.h:40:8: error: unknown type name 'osThreadId_t'
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing a header?

Comment: no, I have an #include "main.h" and #include "cmsis_os.h" in my main.c - I'll try adding #include "cmsis_os.h" in main.h

Comment: If main.h is included before cmsis_os.h in main.c then you need to include cmsis_os,h in main.h. This is because headers work by copy pasting file contents.

Comment: yep that was it! thank you, I will edit my question cause the main problem is that it doesn't seem vTastSuspend and vTastResume can be used for threads